# Computation of a General Summation of Positive Numbers over Integers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> **Question:** Let $(a_k)_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\subset\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers indexed by the integers and $l\in\mathbb{R}$. Is the implication
>   $$
> \forall\epsilon>0,\exists N,n\geq N\implies\left|\sum_{k=-n}^na_k-l\right|<\epsilon\\
> \Downarrow\\
> \forall\epsilon>0,\exists N,m,n\geq N\implies\left|\sum_{k=-m}^na_k-l\right|<\epsilon
> $$
>   true?

**Thoughts:** I think it is. For every $m,n$,
$$
\left|\sum_{k=-m}^na_k-l\right|
$$
is bounded either by
$$
\left|\sum_{k=-m}^ma_k-l\right|+\sum_{k=m+1}^na_k
$$
if $n\geq m$ or by
$$
\left|\sum_{k=-n}^na_k-l\right|+\sum_{k=-m}^{-(n+1)}a_k
$$
if $m\geq n$ and I feel like both bounds go to $0$ as $m,n\to\infty$. However I'm not sure where this would use the hypothesis of positivity of $a_k$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ease of notation, you may denote $\sum_{k = -n}^n a_k$ by $S_n$, therefore the first statement says that the sequence $\{S_n\}$ converges to $l$, therefore it is Cauchy.

Now without loss of generality, assuming $m > n$, hence
\begin{align}
& \left|\sum_{k = -m}^n a_k - l\right| = \left|\sum_{k = -m}^m a_k -  l  - \sum_{k = n + 1}^m a_k\right| \leq \left|\sum_{k = -m}^m a_k - l\right| + \sum_{k = n + 1}^m a_k  \\
< & \left|\sum_{k = -m}^m a_k - l\right| + \sum_{k = n + 1}^m a_k + \sum_{k = -m}^{-(n + 1)} a_k \quad \text{since $a_k$ are positive.}\\
= & \left|S_m - l\right| + S_m - S_n
\end{align}
The result thus follows by using the Cauchy property of $\{S_n\}$.